# Linq to Twitter status update

Tags: c#, twitter

This is my code

For some reason i am unable to update the status i am getting this error .

Your credentials do not allow access to this resource at

var tweet = twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("Hello world");

```
 var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
               ConsumerKey = "", 
               ConsumerSecret = ""
            }
        };

        auth.Authorize();
        //auth.Invalidate();
        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
        var tweet = twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("Hello world");
```

i checked my ConsumerKey and Secret are correct and also i gave my app read write acccess. I am able to get the previous status  , User Name  but i am just unable to tweet a new status

Answer (score 1):

Application Only authorization can only perform operations that are application-level. This differs from other authorizers that let you operate on behalf of a user. The logic is that a user has an account, but an application doesn't. Therefore, you can't tweet on behalf of an application because the tweet can't be assigned anywhere. However, if you tweet on behalf of a user, the tweet goes into that user's list of statuses (their timeline).

LINQ to Twitter has various authorizers and you can see them in use by downloading samples specific to the technology you're using. The downloadable source code also has samples. Here's an example of how to use the PIN authorizer:

```
    static ITwitterAuthorizer DoPinOAuth()
    {
        // validate that credentials are present
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"].IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ||
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"].IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to set twitterConsumerKey and twitterConsumerSecret in App.config/appSettings. Visit http://dev.twitter.com/apps for more info.\n");
            Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return null;
        }

        // configure the OAuth object
        var auth = new PinAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
                ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"]
            },
            AuthAccessType = AuthAccessType.NoChange,
            UseCompression = true,
            GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => Process.Start(pageLink),
            GetPin = () =>
            {
                // this executes after user authorizes, which begins with the call to auth.Authorize() below.
                Console.WriteLine("\nAfter authorizing this application, Twitter will give you a 7-digit PIN Number.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter the PIN number here: ");
                return Console.ReadLine();
            }
        };

        // start the authorization process (launches Twitter authorization page).
        auth.Authorize();
        return auth;
    }
```

This method returns an instance of PinAuthorizer, auth, and you can use it something like this:

```
PinAuthorizer auth = DoPinAuth();
var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
ctx.UpdateStatus("Hello LINQ to Twitter!");
```

*** Update ***

The preceding code was from the old version of LINQ to Twitter. Here's an example of how to do it with the newer async version:

```
    static IAuthorizer DoPinOAuth()
    {
        var auth = new PinAuthorizer()
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"],
                ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"]
            },
            GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => Process.Start(pageLink),
            GetPin = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "\nAfter authorizing this application, Twitter " +
                    "will give you a 7-digit PIN Number.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter the PIN number here: ");
                return Console.ReadLine();
            }
        };

        return auth;
    }
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
        var auth = DoPinOAuth();
        await auth.AuthorizeAsync();
        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
        await twitterCtx.TweetAsync("Hello LINQ to Twitter!");
```

For more information, you can find [Documentation](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation) and [Source](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt) code. The source code has demos in the *New\Demos* folder.

Comment: LinqToTwitter API has changed (now all calls Async and breaking name changes); none of this works anymore and examples/source on LinqToTwitter site all full of same errors. If anyone knows of an updated version please post.

Comment: @Rudy I updated my answer. The API documentation (https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Making%20API%20Calls&referringTitle=Documentation) contains queries in both the 2.x and 3.x versions so you will be able to see the difference in case you come across older code examples.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method on the TwitterContext named UpdateStatus, which you would use like this:

```
twitterCtx.UpdateStatus(" Your text goes here ");
```

You'll need to authorize with OAuth for this to work, so take the PIN option in the demo.  After you're authorized, you can call UpdateStatus.

Comment: From where do i get the PIN option ?

Comment: How would i know whether status is updated on the Twitter or not.